# Cannot uncache HTML file

Tags: apache, caching

I cannot seem to uncache this file https://www.soundshelter.net/land.html

I am not having this issue with any other files on the server

I have deleted the file from the server but its still being served, as well a making multiple amendments - nothing changes. I am using Cloudflare and have tried disabling Cloudflare completely, as well as clearing the file from the Cloudflare cache but nothing is working.

The response headers are below.

```
cache-control:max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, public
cf-ray:29e0a43963c604b6-SYD
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:text/html
date:Thu, 05 May 2016 02:07:54 GMT
expires:Wed, 4 May 2016 05:00:00 GMT
last-modified:Wed, 09 Mar 2016 07:51:39 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:cloudflare-nginx
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
x-cache:MISS from soundshelter.net
```

The last-modified is wrong, I changed the file today.